# Displaying a single value of an attribute using mysql_fetch_field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to fetch and display the user_id(that is auto-incremented) from my table after a user is successfully registered and his user information are stored in the same table. Here goes my code. I need help on the last few lines.

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $mname=$_POST['mname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO `user`(`f_name`,`m_name`,`l_name`,`email`,`password`,`address`,`pincode`,`phone`) VALUES('$fname','$mname','$lname','$email','$pwd','$address','$pincode','$phone')";

    $rs=mysql_query($sql);

    if($rs==1)
    {
        echo 'You have been registered successfully!';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Registration failed!";
    }
}
$src="SELECT `user_id` from `user` where `email`=$email";
$res=mysql_query($src);

$row=mysql_fetch_field($res);

echo $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $row[0];
```

`$row` is an array of fields, even if in your case it contains only one element. For example, if you use

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM ...
```

then `$row` is an array of 3 elements, `$row[0]` being for `a`, `$row[1]` for `b`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> **mysql_fetch_field — Get column information from a result and return as an object.**

```
$row=mysql_fetch_field($res,0);
if(!row)
 {
   echo "There is no record";
 }
else
 {
   echo $row->user_id;
 }
```

Check [**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php)  here

Comment: Have you checked my posted answer?

Comment: i did as per your suggestion. but i am getting 2 errors. the first one says "mysql_fetch_field() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C://....

Comment: Check updated answer and what you get just tell me and there is one record for each email id?

Comment: Check updated answer and mention in which line you got error?

Comment: If you solve or still get any error please give confirmation reply

Comment: this is my piece of code now.   
 $src="SELECT `user_id` from `user` where `email`=$email"; $res=mysql_query($src);
 
 $row=mysql_fetch_field($res);
 
 echo $src;
 echo $row -> user_id;  i am getting an error in $row=mysql_fetch_field($res); and echo $row -> user_id;

Comment: Try with `$row=mysql_fetch_field($res,0);` and give confirmation reply.